# Загрузка соседнего элемента ViewPager

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы в `ViewPager` был загружен соседний элемент слева и справа от видимого? Сейчас там пока не сдвинешь экран, соседние не загружаются.

```
ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

не помогает.

У меня изображения грузятся из файла в BigImageView в макете:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ListPathNameImg16.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        final View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.z_maket_pager_item_for_img16, container, false);
        // Библиотека BigImageView
        BigImageView bigImageView = (BigImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mBigImage);
        bigImageView.showImage(Uri.parse(  ListPathNameImg16[position] ));
        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Создавайте фрагменты заранее, а при перелистывании только добавляйте их во `viewPager`

Comment: Я добавил код к вопросу, у меня не фрагменты, а макет с BigImageView.. Загружаю в них большие изображения с локальных файлов, отсюда при слайдинге сперва идет черный экран на время загрузки на несколько секунд при перелистывании..